# Parsing FB Graph API data Cleanly

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently working to parse through FB api data. Take the following for example...

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "ID", 
      "name": "Creative!"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "ID", 
      "name": "a name"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "after": "fdsagfsganhdfs==", 
      "before": "gfdwiolrukjhteqrfgbh"
    }
  }, 
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 2
  }
}
```

This is an example of what is returned when the Graph API is queried for likes. The issue I am having is that I want a clean way to get the total_count out of this data. Often times it will come in without the summary field if there are no 'likes'. This is easily parsed by doing a few if isset() and if array_key_exists but I will be dealing with a lot of data and this use case applies to many different type of data from FB. Any advice on just getting the total_count field? FQL would work but seems to be deprecated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the `total_count` field is in fact the sum of the number of elements in the `data` array then you can simply use the [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function in PHP to count the length of the array.

Comment: that´s not a good idea, because the api only returns a specific amount of entries. if there are more, you would have to use pagination. meaning, the count may not include all entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
$json_array = json_decode($fb_json_string, true);
$total_count = (isset($json_array['total_count']))? $json_array['total_count']:((isset($json_array['summary']['total_count']))? $json_array['summary']['total_count']:0);
```

I don't know if I can make it any uglier, it's simply a suggestion though.